# Have an alias for a 'grouped by' field in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was wondering if there is any way to apply a conditional alias to a text box field which is being used to group results in an Access Report.

To help explain, I have provided an image of the design view of my report.
The 'Region' box in the Region Header is being grouped by the first 7 characters.

[image]

I  have regions such as "Vic - Melbourne Central", "Vic - Melbourne South", and "Vic - Melbourne East". They are being grouped by 7 characters as that ensures all Regions starting with "Vic - M" are grouped together as I want. However I then want the Region field in the Region Header to display "Melbourne". It currently displays "Vic - Melbourne Central" as it is the first value in order.

Is this possible?
Could I have some VBA code that on report open it searches for Region = "Vic - Melbourne Central" and outputs "Melbourne"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes will have to be made to the report's query. You can have a Function split the name and simply call it in your query:

```
Public Function RegionName(Value As Variant) As String
    If Not IsNull(Value) Then RegionName = Split(Value, " ")(2)
End Function
```

To call it:

```
SELECT  RegionName(T.Region) AS _RegionName
FROM T;
```

Result:

```
'Input:   Vic - Melbourne Central
'Output:  Melbourne
```