# Grouping by LIKE operators

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a small database in Access which has information about customers.

In this database, the original creators had specified a Primary Key (let's call this `ID`).

There's also a column for (as you've guessed) customer names.

On this report that I'm working on, what I essentially want is *similar customer names* grouped into one row.

Like for example if I have the following sets of customers:

**Malaysia**

**Malaysia Airlines**

**Malaysia Pipeline**

Note that these are all the same customers **but** the IDs are different (as you can assume....`ID` is an auto incremented field...1,2,3).

I'm not sure if this is possible..or if I'd have to write some VBA to capture this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd need to be more specific about what counts as "similar"

Comment: Same names...i.e. Malaysian airlines and Malaysia are all considered logically as one customer

Comment: But those aren't the same.  Is it that the entirely of one name can be contained in the other?

Comment: @jwolf, yes technically speaking they aren't the same. However, it is expected that one name will be contained in the other.

Comment: Rahul, there is a solution here for you.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149877/have-an-alias-for-a-grouped-by-field-in-access-report/47153797#47153797

Comment: The way I would go about it is add one more field and call it `PrimaryID` or something similar. Then use VBA to loop through records and search for similar names. This is the tricky part as you have to figure out what similar names are. One way is as mentioned to check for one being completely included in the other. Assign the same `PrimaryID` to all records with similar names probably by using the ID of the first matching record. After that is done you can group by that new field. You can have that function run on a schedule or trigger to account for new records.

Comment: I have added two additional parts to the solution.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick.  This will eliminate all of the rows where the name has a more concise version of itself somewhere in the table (i.e. where another name exists that is a substring of the name being eliminated).  Since this works by deletion, I'm putting everything in a temp table first to protect your original data.

```
select * into #tmp from your_table

delete t1
    from #tmp t1
    inner join #q t2 on t1.[name] like '%' + t2.[name] + '%' and t1.[name] <> t2.[name]

select * from #tmp
```

You can then use this temp table as a kind of master list and, if need be, join to and group the original table, like this:

```
select t1.[name], count(*) - 1 as number_of_aliases, sum(t2.number_of_passengers) as number_of_passengers, avg(t2.avg_ticket_price) as avg_ticket_price
    from #tmp t1
    left join your_table t2 on t1.[name] like '%' + t2.[name] + '%'
    group by t1.[name]
    order by t1.[name]
```

...or get a simple listing all of the aliases, like this:

```
select t1.[name], t2.[name]
    from #tmp t1
    left join your_table t2 on t1.[name] like '%' + t2.[name] + '%'
    order by t1.[name], t2.[name]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not Access SQL. It also does not do what the OP wants, which is to group by similar names not to delete.

Comment: @SunKnight0, agreed. This statement doesn't run in SQL and it's not what I wanted. I'll take a look into what you said and I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: The chosen answer did not work. I had to use @SunKnight0's example and add a `PrimaryID`.